# WPF layout suitable for display of binary data

Tags: c#, wpf, performance, grid-layout, flowdocument

I have a WinForms display of some captured network data (binary).  I'm trying to move to WPF as a learning exercise, and because it should be more maintainable going forward.

As you may have seen, the most common display format for binary data is a dual-column layout showing both the numeric value of each value on the left and string display of octets corresponding to printable ASCII characters on the right.

I also want to be able to independently change the color of each value to highlight detected changes.

[image]

So far I've tried with a `RichTextBox`, where the `FlowDocument` is populated by a `Table`.  There's a single `TableRowGroup` and two columns, one for numeric display and one for string display.

A loop recreates the `TableRowGroup` each time the data changes.  Every 16 bytes of data forms a new `TableRow` containing a single `Paragraph`.  The values within the `TableCell` are managed as a `Run` each.  `Run` objects corresponding to values requiring coloring are further nested in a `Span` before being placed into the `Paragraph`.

This works, but is noticeably slower than a WinForms `RichTextBox` for moderate data sizes.  I suppose WPF is not really designed to have ~4000 `Run` instances in a single `FlowDocument`.

Also, I'm told that imperative creation of so many `TableCell` and `Run` objects is not the intended approach for WPF.  But I'm not quite sure how to map this to a viewmodel either, how to trigger property changes for new data as well as changed display options.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.  Support for copy-to-clipboard is highly desirable.

```
    internal void RenderMessageDiff(GameMessage oldMsg, GameMessage newMsg)
    {
        if (newMsg == null) return;

        var tablerows = new TableRowGroup();

        if (oldMsg == null) oldMsg = newMsg;

        var aby = newMsg.payload;
        for (int offset = 0; offset < aby.Length - 1; offset += 16)
        {
            var leftCol = new Paragraph();
            var rightCol = new Paragraph();
            int blocklen = Math.Min(16, aby.Length - offset);
            switch (selectDisplayFormat.SelectedValue as string)
            {
                case "u1":
                    for (int i = 0; i < blocklen; ++i)
                    {
                        if (i > 0) leftCol.Inlines.Add(new Run(","));
                        var v = new Run(aby[offset + i].ToString());
                        if (aby[offset + i] == oldMsg.payload[offset + i])
                            leftCol.Inlines.Add(v);
                        else
                            leftCol.Inlines.Add(new Span(v) { Foreground = Brushes.Red });
                    }
                    break;

                case "u2":
                    for (int i = 0; i + 1 < blocklen; i += 2)
                    {
                        if (i > 0) leftCol.Inlines.Add(new Run(","));
                        var v = new Run(newMsg.ConvertUInt16LE(offset + i).ToString());
                        if (newMsg.ConvertUInt16LE(offset + i) == oldMsg.ConvertUInt16LE(offset + i))
                            leftCol.Inlines.Add(v);
                        else
                            leftCol.Inlines.Add(new Span(v) { Foreground = Brushes.Red });
                    }
                    break;

                case "u4":
                    for (int i = 0; i + 3 < blocklen; i += 4)
                    {
                        if (i > 0) leftCol.Inlines.Add(new Run(","));
                        var v = new Run(newMsg.ConvertUInt32LE(offset + i).ToString());
                        if (newMsg.ConvertUInt32LE(offset + i) == oldMsg.ConvertUInt32LE(offset + i))
                            leftCol.Inlines.Add(v);
                        else
                            leftCol.Inlines.Add(new Span(v) { Foreground = Brushes.Red });
                    }
                    break;
                case "x1":
                default:
                    for (int i = 0; i < blocklen; ++i)
                    {
                        if (i > 0) leftCol.Inlines.Add(new Run(" "));
                        var v = new Run(aby[offset + i].ToString("X2"));
                        if (aby[offset + i] == oldMsg.payload[offset + i])
                            leftCol.Inlines.Add(v);
                        else
                            leftCol.Inlines.Add(new Span(v) { Foreground = Brushes.Red });
                    }

                    break;
            }
            Span changeRun = null;
            for (int i = 0; i < blocklen; ++i)
            {
                char c = (char)aby[offset + i];
                if (c < 32 || c >= 127) c = '.';
                var v = new Run(c.ToString());
                if (aby[offset + i] == oldMsg.payload[offset + i])
                {
                    rightCol.Inlines.Add(v);
                    changeRun = null;
                }
                else
                {
                    if (changeRun == null)
                        rightCol.Inlines.Add(changeRun = new Span(v) { Foreground = Brushes.Red });
                    else
                        changeRun.Inlines.Add(v);
                }
            }

            tablerows.Rows.Add(new TableRow()
            {
                Cells = { new TableCell(leftCol), new TableCell(rightCol) }
            });
        }

        textMessageDiff.RowGroups.Clear();
        textMessageDiff.RowGroups.Add(tablerows);
    }
```

Comment: It is this just simply for display?  is there any reason the values would need to be edited from the UI?

Comment: @kmacdonald: No editing.  But other non-trivial interactions are helpful.  Copy to clipboard.  Selection of a subset for further processing.  Searching.

Comment: @kmacdonald: Since colorization doesn't affect positioning, is there a way I could do this with a single `Run` per paragraph and just override the rendering?  Should I be using a `Grid` or `ListView` instead?

Comment: If you really want to get into WPF i would suggest taking a look at how to really take advantage of the MVVM approach.  Your example is a prime candidate for using An ItemsControl with a Datatemplate that will represent Each Row visually.  Your datatemplate could consist of a single textblock.  By simply binding to your Row Collection you could get a uniform set of rows to display... This is getting long winded. I will write up something as an answer to the best of my knowledge.

Comment: @kmacdonald: Even though my data is allocated multiple values per row?  I suppose I can break it into slices that map to rows, if that makes MVVM work better.

Comment: yes you could even have a itemControl to display each single byte value.  so basically you would end up with a "Double array" of ItemControls.

Comment: Can you post a sample screenshot of your intended result?

Comment: Also I don't know if this makes any difference, but there will never be items changed individually.  Changing either the source `byte[]` or the format selection will affect all these cells.

Answer (score 1):

Ok here is a crude version of what you could do in WPF.

```
    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding YourBindingRows}">
    <ItemsControl.Resources>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type Row}">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <TextBlock>Text Representation Here</TextBlock>
                <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding YourBindingCells}">
                    <ItemsControl.Resources>
                        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type Cell}">
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding HexValue}"></TextBlock>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ItemsControl.Resources>
                </ItemsControl>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.Resources>
</ItemsControl>
```

You can achieve changing the background color by using ValueConverters and property Binding.  This is another crude example of how to achieve this:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding HexValue}"  Background="{Binding ValueChanged, Converter={StaticResource ValueChangedBackgroundConverter}}">FF</TextBlock>
```

These are crude examples and i think you will have to do some more research into how to really take advantage of MVVM.  However, your project sounds cool and i think it would work really well in the MVVM environment.  For further research look into: `INotifiedPropertyChanged` for binding and `IValueConverter` for changing your color and other UI updates.